# How to ensure auto parameters of a lambda are of the same type?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

If I have a lambda function

```
auto foo = [](auto && a, auto && b){ /* some random c++ code */ };
```

How can I declare that *a* and *b* should be the same type even if that type can be any type?

Comment: If you want to stop compilation when types of a and b are different, why not to add `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(a)>, std::decay_t<decltype(b)> >);` as first line of some random C++ code ?

Comment: `auto foo = [](auto&& a, decltype(a) b) {};`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `static_assert` in the lambda body:

```
#include <type_traits>

auto foo = [](auto && a, auto && b){
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(a)>::type,
            typename std::remove_reference<decltype(b)>::type>::value, 
            "Must be of the same type!");
};
```

You might want to adjust the types for instantiating `std::is_same`, e.g. not consider `const`- or `volatile` qualifiers when comparing etc. (think of `std::decay`). But note that there might be issues like the following:

```
foo("abc", "de"); // fails to compile
```

as the deduced type here is a character array, not `const char*`.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's tagged with C++14, but here's a C++20 solution just in case:

```
auto foo = []<typename T>(T && a, T && b){ /* some random c++ code */ };
```

Comment: A nice intro to template lambda for c++20 https://www.bfilipek.com/2020/08/lambda-generic.html